# What is the reason for the warning "Unquoted string … may clash with future reserved word"?

Tags: perl, warnings

I am trying to work through all the warnings in a Perl program, and having some trouble with this one.

```
Unquoted string "lib" may clash with future reserved word at /home/user/bin/ttt.v01.pl line 17.
    line 17: use lib ( "${HOME}/.lib" );
Unquoted string "sync" may clash with future reserved word at /home/user/bin/ttt.v01.pl line 23.
    line 23: our $SYNC_HOSTS = "${HOME}/.sync.hosts";
Unquoted string "config" may clash with future reserved word at /home/user/bin/ttt.v01.pl line 28.
    line 28: our $USAGE_TEXT = "[-hd] -a <config> -l <location>";
```

From [perldiag](http://p3rl.org/diag):

> Unquoted string "%s" may clash with future reserved word
>
> (W reserved) You used a bareword that might someday be claimed as a reserved word. It's best to put such a word in quotes, or capitalize it somehow, or insert an underbar into it. You might also declare it as a subroutine.

I have these all double quoted, and so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could post a minimal script reproducing one of this warnings.

Comment: Please edit your question to include lines 1 through 17 of `ttt.v01.pl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, maybe you have an unmatched double quote before line 17, which cause the compiler to report wrong warnings?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. It's flagging the `lib` in '/.lib' not in the 'use', because it thinks the one after the `use` is quoted.

Answer (score 0):

I smell a missing quotation mark!

Are you using a program editor or are you using Notepad?

Most program editors have syntax highlighting which can easily help you find the missing quotation mark. I use `VIM` which puts quoted strings in red and Perl functions in green. If I suddenly see all of my various Perl functions in red, and quoted text isn't in red, I immediately know I'm missing a quote somewhere.

Edit your question and include the first 20 lines of your program.